# How can I convert an ICAO (Georgian) CPL to an EASA CPL?

Tags: icao, easa, cpl

I have an ICAO CPL issued by Georgia. The Republic of Georgia is not a member of EASA, but it is included in the category *Countries with whom EASA has a Working Arrangement*. I have 150 flight hours, 100 in an [Aeroprakt A-22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeroprakt_A-22_Foxbat) and 50 in a Cessna.

In the future I am going to study the EASA ATPL theory course in an EASA member state and afterwards convert my ICAO CPL to an EASA CPL. Please let me know what kind of procedures do I need to follow? (In addition to sitting the exams in 14 subjects). I know that I also need to sit flight exams and I need further information about that. Is it worth converting my license to EASA or not?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [your previous question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/37029/62). Usually, you should edit a question to add more information instead of opening a new one, but you've given more useful information here, so I've voted to close the older question.

Comment: "How to" - the best option I'd bet is contacting the local authority (mobility / transport government entity) and they may give you the best answer.